# pattern occurrences in string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this `'101111001101101100210010010'`.

It contains 0,1,and 2. I want to find all the non-overlapping `'111'` pattern and their next value after the pattern. For example `'0**111***1*0**111***0*'`, the total occurrences are 2 and the next value is one 1 and one 0.

Comment: You can use regular expressions.

Comment: Please provide code snippet you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using `re` module:

```
import re

s = "0111101110"
r = re.findall(r"111(.?)", s)

print("Total:", len(r))
for o in r:
    print(o)
```

Prints:

```
Total: 2
1
0
```